# My code doesn't see message.content except when pinging bot / TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, discord.py, huggingface-api

I wrote discord bot based on dialoGPT LM, using huggingface's InferenceAPI. (i tested this code in terminal, it works perfectly fine). Bot launches and passing initialization, but when im trying to send any message it gives me this error in the console. I checked this exact problem here, but there wasn't normal explanation what did helped with author's problem. Im sending picture of errors (there is another one that maybe comes from the first) and full code there, except for API tokens for obvious reasons
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foD5o.png)

```
import requests
import discord
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import io

API_URL = "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/microsoft/DialoGPT-medium"
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer *huggingface token*"}

client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
text = ''

def query(payload):
    response = requests.post(API_URL, headers=headers, json=payload)
    return response.json()
    
def write_doc(text):
       file = open('c:/Users/SuSl1KK/Documents/Code/Project_Alma/v1/corpus.txt', 'r')
       Temp = file.read()
       file.close()
       file = open('c:/Users/SuSl1KK/Documents/Code/Project_Alma/v1/corpus.txt', 'w')
       file.write(Temp + text)
       file.close() 
       return
       
def txtToSpeech(text_to_say, voice_client):
    tts = gTTS(text=text_to_say, lang='en')
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    tts.write_to_fp(fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    if voice_client and voice_client.is_connected():
        voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(fp))
    return
        
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('!come here'):
        channel = message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        return
    
    if message.content.startswith('!bye'):
        voice_client = message.guild.voice_client
        if voice_client:
            await voice_client.disconnect()
            return
            
    if message.content.startswith('!help'):
        await message.channel.send('Here is commands to control me: \n !come here - join voice chat \n !bye - disconnect from voice chat')
        return
        
    Ans = query({"inputs": message.content})
    await message.channel.send(Ans["generated_text"])
    text = text + 'input: ' + message.content + '\n' + 'output: ' + Ans["generated_text"] + '\n\n'
    write_doc(text)

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        if client.user in after.channel.members:  
            voice_client = await after.channel.connect()

            while voice_client.is_connected():
                audio_data = voice_client.listen()
                try:
                    speech_into_text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data)
                    Ans = query({"inputs": speech_into_text})
                    txtToSpeech(Ans, voice_client)
                    text = text + 'input: ' + speech_into_text + '\n' + 'output: ' + Ans["generated_text"] + '\n\n'
                    write_doc(text)
                except sr.UnknownValueError:
                    pass

client.run('*discord token*')
```

As you can see, i tried to do what previous post author did - adding "return" to all the functions, even if they don't need it, but as expected it didn't helped

Edit: i tried printing the response.json(), somewhy my code doesn't read the message.content (except when i ping my bot) and sends empty prompt, so this is a problem, but beside that, even when the response.json() contains the 'generated_text', it returns this:
Answer = Ans['generated_text']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This error says that the response you get on the `query` function does not contain the "generated_text" key.
You can print the value of `response.json()` to check what was the response.

Comment: At some point, you get `None` instead of what you expected. The error is just a consequence of that. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, please provide a [mcve] in your questions and include error messages as text.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. When i've tried to trace problem with empty inputs, i've changed return to print() in LM function, so it just wasn't returning anything, causing this error. Also, bot couldn't read text messages because of incorrect intents both in Code and Developer Portal